# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, specflow, gherkin

I am trying to automate a test case through Specflow, by using the Gherkin format, but I keep having the same error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="customer_firstname"]"}

The name of the textbox is customer_firstname and I do not get it why it is showing this error.

The website that I am testing is:

http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account

The Gherkin file:

```
Feature: Register in the website

  Scenario Outline: Register a new user
    Given That I am on the Register page
    And The website will start by entering 
    | email              |
    | gti19001@demo2.com |
    When User enters their credentials
     | firstName | lastName | password     |
     | DEmo      | Demo     | 12345        |
    When The client will enter 
      | Address              | City      | State | Zip   | MobilePhone |
      | Fake adress, 12, efj | Something |     1 | 35242 | +1 5893246 4863 |
    Then Click on the register button
```

The Step Definition file is:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;
using WebsiteTestingSpecflow.Pages;

namespace WebsiteTestingSpecflow.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class RegisterStep
    {

        RegisterPage registerPage = null;

        [Given(@"That I am on the Register page")]
        public void GivenThatIAmOnTheRegisterPage()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account");
            registerPage = new RegisterPage(webDriver);
        }

        [Given(@"The website will start by entering")]
        public void GivenTheWebsiteWillStartByEntering(Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();

            registerPage.Register(data.email.ToString());
 registerPage.VerifyEmail();
        }

        [When(@"User enters their credentials")]
        public void WhenUserEntersTheirCredentials(Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();

            registerPage.RegisterCredentials(data.firstName.ToString(), data.lastName.ToString(), data.password.ToString());
        }


        [When(@"The client will enter")]
        public void WhenTheClientWillEnter(Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();

            registerPage.RegisterInformation(data.Address.ToString(), data.City.ToString(), data.State.ToString(), data.Zip.ToString(), data.MobilePhone.ToString());
        }

        [Then(@"Click on the register button")]
        public void ThenClickOnTheRegisterButton()
        {
            registerPage.RegisterBtn();
        }
    }
    }
```

And the file where the functions are implemented are:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace WebsiteTestingSpecflow.Pages
{
    class RegisterPage
    {
        public IWebDriver Webdriver { get; }

        public RegisterPage(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            Webdriver = webDriver;
        }


        //UI Elements of Registration
        public IWebElement txtEmailRegister => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("email_create"));

        public IWebElement btnRegisterVerify => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#SubmitCreate > span"));

        public IWebElement txtName => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("customer_firstname"));

        public IWebElement txtSurname => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("customer_lastname"));

        public IWebElement txtPassword => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("passwd"));

        public IWebElement txtAddress => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("address1"));

        public IWebElement txtCity => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("city"));

        public IWebElement txtState => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("id_state"));

        public IWebElement txtZIP => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("postcode"));

        public IWebElement txtPhone => Webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("phone_mobile"));

        public IWebElement btnRegister => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#submitAccount > span"));


        public void Register(string Email)
        {
            txtEmailRegister.SendKeys(Email);
            
        }

        public void RegisterCredentials(string Username, string Lastname, string password)
        {

            txtName.SendKeys(Username);
            txtSurname.SendKeys(Lastname);
            txtPassword.SendKeys(password);
        }

        public void RegisterInformation(string address, string city, string State, string zip, string phone)
        {
            txtAddress.SendKeys(address);
            txtCity.SendKeys(city);
            txtState.SendKeys(State);
            txtZIP.SendKeys(zip);
            txtPhone.SendKeys(phone);
        }

        public void VerifyEmail() => btnRegisterVerify.Submit();

        public void RegisterBtn() => btnRegister.Submit();
    }
}
```

The test output:

[image]

Does anybody know why this may be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does something happen after entering the e-mail address?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a representative example of the HTML?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have included in the question the link to the website that I am testing. Normally it should be that after I entered the email and pressed the Create an account button, it should redirect me to another page but it is not happening.  Maybe it is not recognizing the button?

Comment: You are never hitting the button to go to the next page after you enter your email. The page you link as starting at, asks first to create or login.  You need to hit create account first

Comment: @JoshAdams Yes you were right, I forgot to enter the method to enter the button. I did fix it, but I still am having the same problem with the Exception.

Comment: But now exception thrown on some other code line? Could you put the updated exception trace here?

Comment: @Prophet The exception is in the same line of code. I entered a screenshot of the test report. So it does enter the email and press the button, but it cannot press the textbox customer_firstname.

Comment: Possibly you need to add some wait there?

Comment: @Prophet May I ask you, how can I add it in there and in what place of the code?

Comment: Sure, I tried to answer you. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is not found, because you need to finish automating the page you are on.

1. [image]

   Notice that you need to click the "Create an account" button.
2. [image]

   It is subtle, but the page fades in. While it is fading in, the elements cannot be interacted with, so you need to wait.

You will need the following changes:

1. The page with the e-mail registration text field is *not* the registration page. It is the HomePage, so I would create a page model for that:

   ```
   public class HomePage
   {
       private readonly IWebDriver driver;
       private readonly WebDriverWait wait;

       private IWebElement EmailInput => driver.FindElement(By.Name("email_create"));
       private IWebElement CreateAccountButton => driver.FindElement(By.Name("SubmitCreate"));

       public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
       {
           this.driver = driver;
           this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
       }

       public RegisterPage Register(string email)
       {
           EmailInput.SendKeys(email);
           CreateAccountButton.Click();
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(By.TagName("body")));

           return new RegisterPage(driver);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify RegisterPage to wait for certain elements to be clickable to account for the page not being interactable while it fades in:

   ```
   public class RegisterPage
   {
       private readonly WebDriverWait wait;

       public IWebDriver Webdriver { get; }

       // UI elements ....

       public RegisterPage(IWebDriver webDriver)
       {
           Webdriver = webDriver;
           wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
       }

       public void RegisterCredentials(string Username, string Lastname, string password)
       {
           // Wait for the page to fade in
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("customer_firstname")));
           txtName.SendKeys(Username);
           txtSurname.SendKeys(Lastname);
           txtPassword.SendKeys(password);
       }

       public void RegisterInformation(string address, string city, string State, string zip, string phone)
       {
           // Wait for the page to fade in so you are not required
           // to call RegisterCredential before RegisterInformation.
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("address1")));
           txtAddress.SendKeys(address);
           txtCity.SendKeys(city);
           txtState.SendKeys(State);
           txtZIP.SendKeys(zip);
           txtPhone.SendKeys(phone);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is probably important to mention that this should really be a different page object rather than register page.  The create account or login page should be its' own, and registration its' own.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to add some wait.
Try adding

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("customer_firstname")));
```

before

```
txtName.SendKeys(Username);
```

Comment: The `txtName` property itself is throwing an exception, it looks like.